# How to set Cursor to a Particular Cell of a SWT Tree

Tags: java, tree, cursor, swt, treeviewer

I have a SWT `Tree`, and I want to set the cursor to a particular cell of that SWT Tree.
I have access of `TreeViewer`.

The screenshot below shows the cursor at column 1. I did it manually, but I want to do it programatically.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`TreeViewer#editElement(Object element, int column)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewer.html#editElement%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29).

Where `element` is the model element and `column` the column in your table.

The Javadoc states:

> Starts editing the given element at the given column index.

Comment: but how to get ColumnViewer from a TreeViewer

Comment: `TreeViewer` **is** a `ColumnViewer`, so `TreeViewer` has the method `editElement(...)`.